# How to force gcc preprocessor to preserve whitespace?

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor, whitespace

For the code:

```
int  i;
```

gcc preprocessor outputs:

```
int i;
```

How to force it to preserve whitespace?

I call preprocessor with: gcc -E somefile.c command.

Comment: Can you give some context here?  When you call it with -E it removes anything that isn't pure code.  Why would you need it to preserve whitespace?  Maybe there's a better way to do what you're trying to do?

Comment: I don't think so. I working on static analysis tool which works with preprocessed file, but report about errors in the original file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use it in traditional mode, ie '-traditional-cpp' as described [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Traditional-Mode.html).

Comment: You are the life saver!

Comment: When combined with `-P` in order to suppress the the line directives, this results in a lot of empty whitespace. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai If you're referring to the extra white space at the *beginning* of the file, I was having the same problem.  And after doing some experimenting, the `-nostdinc` option was what fixed it for me.