# Forbid C preprocessor to change indentation

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Example (note, there is exactly one TAB in this code, displayed as 8 spaces):

```c
int main()
{
   int x = 1;
   if (x == 1)
   {
      x = 2;
      if(x == 2)
      {
         x = 3; /* indented with TAB */
      }
   }
}
```

`g++ -E` and `clang++ -E` both turn this into:

```c
int main()
{
   int x = 1;
   if (x == 1)
   {
      x = 2;
      if(x == 2)
      {
  x = 3;
      }
   }
}
```

Another example:

```c
int main()
{
   int x =   ( 1 + 3);
}
```

->

```
int main()
{
   int x = ( 1 + 3);
}
```

It replaced the tab by a space (in the first example) and replaced consecutive spaces by one (in the second example). Can I force it not to do so?

Comment: Are you using just tabs, just spaces, or a mix of the two? (Turn on "visible whitespace"in your text editor to make sure.)

Comment: In my case, I indent with 3 spaces, and use tabs whenever there are 8 spaces in a row. So it's mixed. But the coding style does not matter, the question is independent of the coding style.

Comment: Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445986/how-to-force-gcc-preprocessor-to-preserve-whitespace) you can pass `--traditional-cpp`. Of course, that involves other changes...

Comment: "*Whether each nonempty sequence of white-space characters other than new-line is retained or replaced by one space character is implementation-defined.*" That's in translation phase 3, before preprocessing directives are executed and macros are expanded (that happens in phase 4).

Comment: @JETM This seems to be the solution, indeed. Unfortunatelly, this flag also seems to have other effects which make it impossible to include some of the standard headers. Is there any other flag?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Normally the output of the preprocessor is internal to the compiler.

Comment: You could probably modify the source of gcc to fix this

Comment: And behavior like this is one reason why many organizations have coding standards that forbid the use of tabs - the expansion of tabs to spaces isn't consistent.  If you don't like the lack of control that the use of tabs causes, the real answer is don't use tabs.

Comment: @KeithThompson We have a C code analyzer (checking many things, one of which is indentation) that understands the [C grammar](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html), but does not have a preprocessor. Hence, we need the preprocessor to translate the code into something without macros.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Avoiding tabs does not help us with the fact that gcc turns multiple spaces into one.

Comment: @Johannes: Then you need a C code analyzer that works on unpreprocessed code. The C preprocessor is part of the compiler, and it's under no obligation to preserver semantically meaningless white space. It's likely that the preprocessor you're using doesn't have the feature you're looking for. Can you identify the analyzer you're using?

Answer (score 4):

*This isn't really an answer to the question "How to get the preprocessor to preserve tabs"; I loosely reinterpreted the question as "How to preserve tabs through preprocessing."*

Unix-like distributions should come with the Posix `expand` and `unexpand` utilities, which, respectively, expand tabs to spaces and replace sequences of spaces with tabs. You can easily use this to preserve leading tabs in their passage through the preprocessor:

```
$ # '-i' is a Gnu extension. Leave it out if you have a Posix expand.
$ expand -i tabbed.c | gcc -E - | unexpand
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 31 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 32 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "<stdin>"
int main()
{
   int x = 1;
   if (x == 1)
   {
      x = 2;
      if(x == 2)
      {
         x = 3;
      }
   }
}
```

(Note: there is a tab at the beginning of the line `x = 3` although it didn't make it through the copy-and-paste into SO.)

The GCC (and clang) preprocessors normalize non-leading whitespace (including comments) into a single space character, so there's not a lot you can do about those. For that reason, in the example above I used the Gnu extension `-i` option to  `expand`, causing it to only expand tabs in leading whitespace. (`unexpand` only looks at leading whitespace unless you provide the `-a` option.) This would only be useful if you put raw tabs inside strings or character literals, instead of `\t`. Presumably you don't do that.

The preprocessor output shown above differs from the result of preprocessing `tabbed.c` directly in that the line directives reference `<stdin>` rather than the name of the file. Prepending `#line 1 "tabbed.c" 1` to the input stream is an imperfect fix but it will at least pass the `#line` directive through. You could use `sed` or some other line editor to modify the generated line number directives.