# Is there a way for C Pre-processor or some other tools to Process a file with white space and preserve it

Tags: c++

Basically, I am attempting to use cpp to process a text file (containing tabular data) with a series of ifdef / ifndef etc.  For example:

```
#ifdef ABCD
    abcd <10 spaces> efgh <10 spaces> ijkl
#else
    zyxw <10 spaces> vuts <10 spaces> rqpo
#endif

I am using "cpp -E -P -D ABCD", i get:
abcd efgh ijkl  // White space removed
```

Is there any way to preserve my white space (10 spaces between strings)?
Thanks

Comment: `gcc` has the [`-traditional-cpp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445986/how-to-force-gcc-preprocessor-to-preserve-whitespace/445996#445996) option.

Comment: Maybe something like [`m4`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_(computer_language)) would be a better fit?

Comment: By "process" do you mean "create"?

Answer (score 0):

Strings of whitespace are not meaningful in a C++ source file.

And, despite your wishes, you are still asking your computer to produce a C++ source file.

**You are using the wrong tool for this job.**

Instead, consider writing some script. That could be in, for example, Python or Bash or [m4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_(computer_language)).

Comment: Is there some problem?